# open excel command not opening the excel file

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

In Ride editor when I am giving open excel the test is failed

Open excel    D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls    default=True
or 
Open excel    D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls    default=False

TEST readexceldemo
Full Name:  Testproj.ExcelDemo.readexceldemo
Start / End / Elapsed:  20190825 02:52:29.280 / 20190825 02:52:29.287 / 00:00:00.007
Status: FAIL (critical)
Message:    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\RobotProjects\Testproj\Demo1.xls'
00:00:00.004KEYWORD ExcelLibrary . Open Excel D:\RobotProjects\Testproj\Demo1.xls, default=True
Documentation:
Opens the Excel file from the path provided in the file name parameter. If the boolean useTempDir is set to true, depending on the

operating system of the computer running the test the file will be opened in the Temp directory if the operating system is Windows

or tmp directory if it is not.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20190825 02:52:29.281 / 20190825 02:52:29.285 / 00:00:00.004
02:52:29.285    FAIL    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\RobotProjects\Testproj\Demo1.xls'

TEST readexceldemo
Full Name:  Testproj.ExcelDemo.readexceldemo
Start / End / Elapsed:  20190825 02:53:45.656 / 20190825 02:53:45.665 / 00:00:00.009
Status: FAIL (critical)
Message:    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls'
00:00:00.006KEYWORD ExcelLibrary . Open Excel D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls, default=True
Documentation:
Opens the Excel file from the path provided in the file name parameter. If the boolean useTempDir is set to true, depending on the

operating system of the computer running the test the file will be opened in the Temp directory if the operating system is Windows

or tmp directory if it is not.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20190825 02:53:45.657 / 20190825 02:53:45.663 / 00:00:00.006
02:53:45.663    FAIL    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls'

Comment: Please follow @Cyrus comment to format your question. Please indicate the version of RIDE and Python (which looks like 2.7).

Comment: If you open up a command prompt and run the command `dir D:/RobotProjects/Testproj/Demo1.xls` what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you show, is from Robot Framework, that did not find the file.
You probably would have the same error if you run the test from command window.

You should try to use backslash separator (which must be doubled). The command would be:

```
Open excel D:\\RobotProjects\\Testproj\\Demo1.xls default=True
```

Comment: forward slashes have been supported on windows for many years.